# Connecting to Internet using TataPhoton 3G dongle(ZTE MF190) Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb-modem, 3g

I have bought a new Tata Docomo Photon 3G Dongle and I want to use it from Ubuntu 12.04.

When I connect the device, its detected but I don't know how to install the software packed within it or connect to internet.

I tried searching for the packages in Ubuntu Software Center but it doesn't work.

I tried manually adding the device in Mobile Broadband section, using different APNs and Service provider names.

It made no difference.

The device is ZTE MF190(HSUPA). Please tell me how to install the device software or connect to internet without installing the software.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to connect to internet some how beause some packages need to be installed. I had similar issue with my tatadocomo3g dongle. So I connected to internet using win7 and downloaded sakis3g and ran it on ubuntu(I have dual boot OS with win7 and Ubuntu 13.10).

You can get **Sakis3g** from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-n4n0/files/sakis3g.tar.gz/download). Extract it and open a terminal and run sakis3g.

Then follow only **steps**  explained in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406975/tata-docomo-3g-dongle-in-linux-mint-or-ubuntu/423768#423768) to connect to internet. Now you are connected to internet.

Then if you want to install photon dashboard then follow these steps (remove **Photon3G** folder in  **/opt** if you have already installed it once and if not working.)

1. Before start installing open softwarecenter and install **wvdial** (some times if yout software center not detecting connection then run   `sudo stop network-manager` in terminal)
2. Open the **Linux** folder in **Photon3G datacard** and copy **PCL_TATADOCIND.tar.gz** to **Desktop** folder and extract it.
3. Open it go to **tools** then  open **deb** then open **qt** and open `libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-0ubuntu3_i386.deb` using **softwarecenter** and install it, also install `libaudio2_1.9.1-1_i386.deb`.
4. Then go back to **deb/wvdial** folder and install `libwvstreams4.4-base_4.4.1-0.2ubuntu2_i386.deb` then after that `libwvstreams4.4-extras_4.4.1-0.2ubuntu2_i386.deb`  then `libuniconf4.4_4.4.1-0.2ubuntu2_i386.deb` , `libxplc0.3.13_0.3.13-1build1_i386.deb` and `libmng1_1.0.9-1_i386.deb` one by one using **softwarecenter**. (If it shows *already latest version installed* then no problem otherwise install.)
5. Now after installed all packages you are ready to install.
6. Open terminal type

   cd Desktop/

   cd PCL_TATADOCIND/

   sudo sh install.sh

Now it will install properly and Photon3G software will start working.

> This is how I installed Tataphoton3g software and it is working in ubuntu 13.10 :-).

Comment: Your answer seems effective. I followed all the steps. Some packages in qt and wvdail aren't getting installed. Despite that, I used sudo sh install.sh. Now it's showing installed successfully. But in sakis3G it's unable to connect to 3G. Says failed to connect. Please help!

Comment: If you run sakis3g with settings mentioned as [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406975/tata-docomo-3g-dongle-in-linux-mint-or-ubuntu/423768#423768) you should be able to connect. Also try connecting with modem in other usb port.

Comment: Awesome... It works like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

Plug your device and open Terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wvdial
sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

Uncomment username and password field

```
Username = YOUR USERNAME
Password = YOUR PASSWORD
```

Add this line at end

Stupid Mode = 1

Save file. Now in Terminal

```
sudo wvdial
```

Now , you can try to ping Google to make sure connection works.

Comment: After running final command, it gave me: --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

On your terminal:

```
cd /dev/disk/by-id

ls
```

look for something similar to `usb-HUAWEI_Mass_Storage_ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ-0:0`
mount this device on a mount path

```
mount usb-HUAWEI_Mass_Storage_ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ-0\:0 /mnt
cd /mnt
sh ./install_linux
```

as soon as the installation is done, you can Tata Photon GUI will come and you can continue browsing as you used to do before.

Source: http://jainkkapil.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/tata-photon-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: After running the ls command, I didn't find the HUAWEI mass storage. Instead there are these two:  usb-ZTE_MMC_Storage_MF6310ZTED010000-0:1
usb-ZTE_USB_SCSI_CD-ROM_MF6310ZTED010000-0:0            So I tried running mount usb-ZTE_MMC_Storage_MF6310ZTED010000-0:1
and it said mount: can't find usb-ZTE_MMC_Storage_MF6310ZTED010000-0:1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab