# Tata Docomo 3g Dongle in Linux [Mint or Ubuntu ]

Tags: wireless, 3g

I need help connecting the **Tata Docomo 3g** Dongle in Linux.I searched everywhere on the internet and could not find any solution.I think all the required files are provided with the device : 
Here is the overview of the folders  :

```
tools
install.sh
photon3g.tar
zr
```

**In photon3g.tar we have the driver files of the device**

in tools we have :

```
*2 folders :*
deb
rpm

*in deb :*
qt 
wvdial

*in rpm :*
libwvstreams-4.5.1-6.fc11.i586
wvdial-1.60-8.fc11.i586
```

Please Help me out!

Comment: What happens when you open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T; cd to the folder in the device; and type the command `./install.sh`? Note you have to add the dot and slash before the command.

Comment: so which are you using Mint or Ubuntu?

Comment: Mint..the problem i am having is how to install all these files ? i can maybe try somethings to try it to connect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have tatadocomo3g. I tried to install setup but it was not working properly because some packages were missing and I was not able to connect internet to dowload those also.

After so much frustration I finally found alternate way using **sakis3g** to connect internet.

I am using dual boot with Win7 and ubuntu 13.10 so I downloaded sakis3g script in win7 and ran it on ubuntu and it worked.

Installation procedure is explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1580427)

Then setup connection by following steps given below

1. run sakis3g then an interactive window will come
2. select > connect to 3G
3. select > USB device
4. select > ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
5. select >  interface #3
6. give apn: tatadocomo3g
7. username:  TIM  |  password:  TIM

actually nothing is required in username and password field, but sakis3g interactive won't allow you to leave username and password blank so just give it as TIM.

It will connect... if not connect modem on different usb port and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I cant believe that I've somehow missed reading ur post for the last 2-3 months.. I was virtualizing windows to use my TataPhoton 3G

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.10. I installed sakis3g using above instructions(http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1580427) After installing, I tried to setup connection. However setting connection failed but surprisingly, internet works! After all thats what I want ;) Looks like some package was missing before and now its present