# My mobile-broadband device does not work on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: networking, usb-modem, 3g

My mobile-broadband device `1c9e:6061 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY WL-72B 3.5G MODEM` does not work on Ubuntu 13.10 or any Ubuntu based distros. But it works well on Fedora 19 and Fuduntu.

on Ubuntu:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 1c9e:6061 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY WL-72B 3.5G MODEM
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0ac8:c349 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04fc:0013 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd ViewMate Desktop Mouse CC2201
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# usb-devices
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1c9e ProdID=6061 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Qualcomm, Incorporated
S:  Product=Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
S:  SerialNumber=000000000002
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)

# dmesg
[  179.197604] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  179.293119] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c9e, idProduct=6061
[  179.293130] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  179.293137] usb 2-1.2: Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
[  179.293142] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
[  179.293147] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000002
[  179.295844] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  179.295918] scsi5 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[  180.295738] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HSPA     MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  180.296575] scsi 5:0:0:1: CD-ROM            HSPA     MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  180.296884] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  180.308339] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[  180.308488] sr 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  180.308570] sr 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 5
[  180.315955] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  180.527311] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[  180.561077] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
```

On Fedora 19

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04fc:0013 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd ViewMate Desktop Mouse CC2201
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:c349 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 14cd:125c Super Top SD card reader
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1c9e:6061 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY WL-72B 3.5G MODEM

# usb-devices
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1c9e ProdID=6061 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Qualcomm, Incorporated
S:  Product=Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
S:  SerialNumber=000000000002
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage

# dmesg
[   74.655202] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c9e, idProduct=6061
[   74.655212] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[   74.655218] usb 2-1.2: Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
[   74.655223] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
[   74.655228] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000002
[   74.660260] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[   77.720190] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[   77.897799] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[   77.986096] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c9e, idProduct=6061
[   77.986107] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[   77.986113] usb 2-1.2: Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
[   77.986118] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
[   77.986123] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000002
[   77.990175] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.3
[   79.014680] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HSPA     MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   79.015669] scsi 7:0:0:1: CD-ROM            HSPA     MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   79.018190] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   79.020417] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   79.023790] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[   79.024252] sr 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[   79.024526] sr 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 5
[   79.256276] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[   79.258015] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[   79.259663] SELinux: initialized (dev sr1, type iso9660), uses genfs_contexts
[   79.551148] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   79.552698] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   79.570265] option 2-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   79.570848] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   79.570911] option 2-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   79.571283] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   79.571338] option 2-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   79.571716] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  115.069111] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[  115.121844] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[  115.146879] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
```

Is there any solution for that? (O.S is Ubuntu 13.10)

Comment: You can use `wvdial` to connect your modem.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. i use this: install wvdial run as root sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial. output sorry no modem found!

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions.TNX for answers.

## 1st:

```
$ sudo su
# gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
```

`DisableSwitching=0` i changed `0` to `1` save.

`# eject /dev/sr1 2> /dev/null` each time I plug the modem in PC.

## 2nd: (is the best)

```
$ sudo su
# gedit /usr/bin/anyname
```

put the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1c9e 6061 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

save exit

Note: `1c9e 6061` is the device ID obtained from the `lsusb` command

```
# chmod +x /usr/bin/anyname
# gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/option.rules
```

put the following:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6061", RUN+="/usr/bin/anyname"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6061", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe option"
```

save exit

```
# reboot
```

Comment: would you accept your own answer as it is the one which works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Else can use sakis3g to connect. Install and run **sakis3g** script, it will open an interactive GUI window. Then provide your mobile broadband details as required (connect to 3G, usb device, Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM,  apn, username and password etc in respective fields.)  See this  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406975/tata-docomo-3g-dongle-in-linux-mint-or-ubuntu/423768#423768) for reference.

Comment: Download sakis3g:
Code:

wget http://www.sakis3g.org/versions/latest/i386/sakis3g.gz
Connecting to www.sakis3g.org (www.sakis3g.org)|37.6.254.137|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying Connecting to www.sakis3g.org (www.sakis3g.org)|37.6.254.137|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying. and so on.

Comment: download from here..... http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-n4n0/files/sakis3g.tar.gz/download