# bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

Tags: echo

I am trying to setup a USB dongle on my device by following the post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424804/my-mobile-broadband-device-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-13-10). I wasn't successful in setting it up and while tracing my steps discovered that

```
echo "1c9e:9ba1" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
```

was resulting in an error. I ran this statement from the terminal and got the following response

```
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

according to the post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319936/cat-write-error-invalid-argument) it means that the device doesn't implement a WRITE method.

Wondering if there is a way to get the echo command to work so that I can get my USB modem working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What happened when you remove the ":" as appear in the link you provided?

Original Answer:

```
echo 1c9e 6061 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

Your case:

Instead of:

```
echo "1c9e:9ba1" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
```

**Try running:**

```
echo "1c9e 9ba1" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
```

Comment: Removing the colon writes to the new_id file.

Comment: After reboot the usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id has disappeared. Funny

Comment: Did you create all scripts mentioned in the answer? I think that during boot, the scripts should create/configure the device.

Comment: I did create all the scripts. Flummoxed how the directories just disappeared.