# ZTE Modem is not detected

Tags: modem, zte

My ZTE Modem is not detected as CDMA Modem instead it is detected as USB storage device
How I can change its mode to CDMA from Mass storage mode,

Here is the demsg output

```
  [  488.321117] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
  [  496.930211] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
  [  496.947491] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=fff5
  [  496.947505] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  [  496.947514] usb 3-2: Product: USB Storage
  [  496.947521] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ZTE, Incorporated
  [  496.947528] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 000000000002
  [  496.949155] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
  [  496.949431] scsi9 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
  [  497.949158] scsi 9:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB Storage FFE9 2.31      PQ:     0 ANSI: 2
  [  497.951145] scsi 9:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFE9 2.31 PQ:    0 ANSI: 2
  [  497.958415] sr1: scsi-1 drive
  [  497.958688] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
  [  497.958868] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
  [  497.964409] sd 9:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
  [  497.976462] sd 9:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
  [  498.059848] systemd-udevd[2537]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr1: No such file    or directory
  [  498.059877] systemd-udevd[2537]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr1: No such file     or directory
```

please help me in this....some times it is automatically changing its mode to modem and most of the time stucking up like this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a tatadocomo 3G data card my dmsg output also looks similar to this. My data card was detected by network manager but I was not able to connect to internet anyhow.

But now I am able to connect to internet with sakis3g. I think this may work for you also.

Sakis3G is a tweaked shell script which is supposed to work out-of-the-box for establishing a 3G connection with any combination of modem or operator. It automatically setups your USB or Bluetooth™ modem, and may even detect operator settings. You should try it when anything else fails!

1. Download  sakis3g from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-n4n0/files/sakis3g.tar.gz/download)
2. Extract it to desktop
3. Open terminal and run

   cd Desktop

   sakis3g

then an interactive window will come then

```
select > connect to 3G
select > USB device
select > ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
select > interface #3 
give apn: tatadocomo3g
username: TIM | password: TIM
```

this is how I connect my 3g modem with sakis3g as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406975/tata-docomo-3g-dongle-in-linux-mint-or-ubuntu/423768#423768)

**you have to enter your apn,  username, password w.r.t your connection  you have**