# Tata Photon 3G Dongle not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb-modem, 3g

When I plug-in the device Tata Photon Plus, it is getting detected and the inbuilt memory can be accessed. 
There was an installation option in the flash memory,  linux folder, which was a bash script. I ran the installation script which ran to completion showing the message that it is successfully installed, and you can open the utility graphically.
I can see the icon of the same, in  but on clicking it, the system  doesn't respond at all.
Kindly help.

Comment: what's your model? can you share the output of `lsusb`? also have you looked at similar questions, [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78164/configuring-tata-photon-usb-modem-huawei-ec156) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/365079/connecting-to-internet-using-tataphoton-3g-donglezte-mf190-ubuntu-12-04)